# Searching & Replacing first characters of an expression in Notepad++ using regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace the "<p>" tag with "<p class="myclass">" class in the following html with Search & Replace (using regular expression) function in Notepad++

```
<p><?php echo $element_arr["a1_discount"]; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $element_arr["b2_discount"]; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $element_arr["c5_discount"]; ?></p>
```

I was able to match the above with the following reg-ex:

```
RegEx: (<p><\?php echo \$element_arr\["[A-Za-z][1-99]_discount"\]; \?>)
```

I tried the following replace reg-ex but it's not working:

```
(<p class="myclass"><\?php echo \$element_arr\["[A-Za-z][1-99]_discount"\]; \?>)
```

It comes out as: `<p class="cool"><?php echo $element_arr["[A-Za-z][1-99]_discount"]; ?></p>`

Can someone help me with this. This will be a huge time-saver as I have lots of editing of such nature to do.

Thanks a lot

dkj

Comment: I think you should use `[A-Za-z][1-9][0-9]?` instead of `[A-Za-z][1-99]` ;).

Comment: will keep that in mind. just starting with regex.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a regex for this. Just search for

`<p>` and replace it with `<p class="myclass">`

Comment: I'm specifically looking to do it with regex and moreover there are other p tags as well where that class should not be applied.

Comment: How about this regex: Replace <p class="[^"]+"> with 
<p class="something else">

Answer (score 0):

In case you do have other `p` tags with various attributes, you can use the following approach:

1. Run the S&R with `(<p[^<>]*\bclass=")[^"]*("[^<>]*>)` regex replacing with `$1myclass$2` (the `Regular Expression` option ON).

This is working for strings like

```
<p class="someclass">text</p>
<p id="new" class="someclass">text</p>
<p id="new" class="someclass" end="true">text</p></code>
```

2. Run the S&R with `<p\b(?![^<>]*\bclass=)([^<>]*)>` replacing with `<p$1 class="myclass">` for paragraph tags without attributes or without `class` attribute.

This is fine for strings like

```
<p>text</p>
<p id="new">text</p>
```

This complexity can be easily removed if you decided to use any HTML parser with a regular programming language.

Comment: Nice. This works but I prefer to have the second step built into the regex. Is that possible. Also it would be nice if you could explain the regex. thanks

Comment: You can't combine the steps because in one case there will be attribute adding and in the other there will be attribute modification. Actually, there is another option that I forgot to cover: when there is no `class` attribute but there are other attributes. I have added this case now.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Find what: `<p>(?=<\?php echo \$element_arr\["[A-Za-z][1-9][0-9]*_discount"\]; \?>)`
Replace with: `<p class="myclass">`

Where `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead that makes sure you have `<?php echo ...` after the tag `<p>`

Comment: Hi, did you test this? Cause this did not work for me although I liked the approach.

Comment: @dkjain: Sorry I've forgotten the `*` after `[0-9]`, ie. `[0-9]*`